# "Access denied" after IP address change (WAMP; Drupal)

Tags: drupal, urls, civicrm.settings.php

I wasted hours of searching Google back and forth, and found no solution:
CiviCRM is set up as an internal only CRM system for an organisation (i.e. IP address 192.168.178.36) - so far, so good. Now I took the server with me to work on CiviCRM, so I changed the IP address to 192.168.2.36 accordingly.

I've changed Apaches httpd.conf, and Apache runs without issues. Drupal seems to come up fine, but whenever I want to access CiviCRM via
http://192.168.2.36/q=civicrm/dashboard
the website answers with

a) the former IP address (192.168.178.36) in the header of the result page,

b) "Access denied - you are not authorized to access this page."

I deleted the content of all drupal cache tables, I deleted the content of the "templates_c" directory - no success :-(

Please, can someone point me into the right direction?

Regards

Bernhard

Comment: Did you change the url (or IP in your case) in both the sites/default/civicrm.settings.php and settings.php files?

Comment: Yes, both `$base_url` (for Drupal) and `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` (for CiviCRM) point to "`http://192.168.2.36`"

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but if you haven't search through both those files for your old ip address, you should.  It may appear other things like CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR and civicrm_root.

Comment: A work around might be to put a cheap router between your server and the work network.  That way you can have the same IP address.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't really isn't' much different from creating a test env minus the whole copying of db and code trees.    There are lots of guides out there on all the things you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a new database isn't necessary.  For folks who encounter similar issues in the future:  after checking your `BASE_URL` setting in `civicrm.settings.php`, delete your `templates_c` folder ([found here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)), clear all CiviCRM caches, and rebuild your menus.  Details on the latter two items [are available here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers).

Answer (score -1):

The answer is hidden deep in the database. I tried to install Drupal again (just the program), and the same message came up. When I then created a new database, everything works as expected.

So be warned that you will need to setup a new database if you plan to move the server to a new location!

Comment: Did you try "Cleanup Caches" at civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1 ?

Comment: "... you will need to setup a new database if you plan to move the server to a new location!" - That's definitively not true - we moved all our projects 3-4 dozen from one data center to another 2y ago and new IPs all around - not saying it's easy but it definitively takes some getting used to and practice moving Drupal/CiviCRM projects around.