# Where are the "ConfigAndLog" and "templates_c" directories?

Tags: templates, logs, debugging, caching

Many Stack Exchange answers say to "check your CiviCRM logs" which can be found in the "ConfigAndLog" directory, or to "delete your templates_c folder".  What are the default locations for the ConfigAndLog and templates_c directories?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two directories are found side-by-side.  The location varies by CMS; see below.  Note that you'll need access to your server's file system.  If you have FTP/SFTP/SSH access, you can use that.  If you have a control panel, check for a "File Manager" plugin:

- **Drupal**: `<drupalroot>/sites/default/files/civicrm/`
- **Joomla**: `<joomlaroot>/media/civicrm/`
- **WordPress**: `<wordpressroot>/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/`
- **WordPress (old)**: `<wordpressroot>/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/`

  - Any CiviCRM version 5.29 and later will never have the "old" location.
- **Backdrop**: `<backdroproot>/files/civicrm/`

Comment: A useful feature development would be a mechanism, as is the case with access to the scheduled jobs log, to provide visibility of the log file through the UI, especially for those people who may not have ready access to the server.

Comment: I'm just seeking a more detailed answer to the specific file [over here](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17047/where-is-the-exact-path-to-the-configandlog-log-file)

Comment: For Wordpress, I'm not sure what version this may have changed (I'm in 4.7) but I think these files are in /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ now

Comment: Jon can you clarify what you mean by WP (old). Are you referring to the WP version, or civi version?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Both are valid defaults.  One was the default in older versions of CiviCRM - I don't know when it changed.  Since a WP site might be an older site that's been upgraded, it's important to check both.

Comment: thank you. so i take it that having the 'old' one on an upgraded site doesn't mean problems.

Answer (score 6):

Another option for seeing the civi logs is adding the extension [CiviCRM Log Viewer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer) which gives a link via the Admin menu to view the error log