# Settings - Outbound Mail are not saved

Tags: joomla, email, database, settings

please help, I have a Joomla 3.6.5 and CiviCRM 4.7.14
I just migrated from the dev site to the live site, and now when I check the Outbound Mail settings in CiviCRM, they are empty.
Everytime I fill them out and press save, once I reaload the settings page, they are empty again.

Please, where is this info stored?

Thank you

Comment: Did you resolve this? Was this an issue on the Outbound Mail settings page alone, or on other admin pages as well?

Comment: Not solved yet, and its only one the Outbound Mail settings page. I checked the DB on civicrm_mail_settings and the info stored there is fine. But when I load the settings page, its as if nothing is configured.

And on the frontend the following error pops up:

There is no valid smtp server setting. Click <a href='/index.php?option=com_civicrm&amp;task=civicrm/admin/setting/smtp&amp;Itemid=306&amp;reset=1'>Administer >> System Setting >> Outbound Email</a> to set the SMTP Server.

Comment: @michaelmacandrew .. any idea why it is not saved?

Comment: I just updated to CiviCRM 4.7.15 and I still have the same issue:

There is no valid smtp server setting. Click <a href='/index.php?option=com_civicrm&amp;task=civicrm/admin/setting/smtp&amp;Itemid=466&amp;reset=1'>Administer >> System Setting >> Outbound Email</a> to set the SMTP Server.

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: wondering if it is not validating, or similar, due to the specifics of the data that you are entering. it might be worth experimenting with just saving one field at a time and seeing what happens. and or trying different settings to the ones you are using (settings that are very similar to the defaults to see if you can identify the error that way.

Comment: no matter what I enter there, it is correctly saved in the db, but not loaded when I reload the database
I can now pin down that the error is in the database.

I created a entire new website, replicated all fields, did all from zero, and it works.
When I link the new code base with the old database, same error happens
When I link the old code base with the new database, it all works

So the error must be somewhere inside the DB, question is where???

Answer (score 1):

The typical troubleshooting steps here would be to check for errors in the [CiviCRM log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) as well as to [check for JavaScript errors](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) in your web browser's console.

Comment: If you find an answer, please post it here and mark it as the correct answer.  If you find additional info but it doesn't completely answer your question, please update your question with any info this yields.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database using phpMyAdmin, the email information is in the civicrm part of the database tables with the table name "civicrm_email".  The default email is probably the first mentioned with the ID of 1.

Have you entered the default email address in Administer>Communications>Organization Address and contact info, as well as set them up in Adminster>Communications>From email addresses?

In the latter,dont forget to:

1. mark the relevant default email address.
2. Include double-quotes (") around the name and angle-brackets (< >)
   around the email address.

Comment: Example: "ClientServices"<clientservices@example.org>

Comment: I checked the DB, I only found a match in the table civicrm_mail_settings
There the information is stored correctly. Not sure if this table is related to the outbout email settings. But still, once I refresh the admin page for the outbound email settings after saving, it is back to empty and I am getting an error in the frontend that there are no outbound email settings stored.

In the civicrm_email I only see a list of all users and their emails. Nothing about the outbound server settings.

Please help me again to find what wrong

Answer (score 0):

The settings for the outbound mailer are stored in the `civicrm_setting` database table. Use the following SQL statement to retrieve them:

```
select * from civicrm_setting
where name='mailing_backend'
```

The result field `value` all the settings in (I suppose) Drupal database storage format. Does it have SMTP server details? For example:

```
s:10:"smtpServer";s:34:"email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Yes, that entry is there and it looks correct to me.
Here the entry:

a:10:{s:5:"qfKey";s:37:"78e0284ea55c139e14adf6104fc4110e_4455";s:8:"entryURL";s:134:"http://www.mydomain.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&amp;task=civicrm/admin/setting/smtp&amp;option=com_civicrm&amp;reset=1";s:15:"outBound_option";s:1:"0";s:13:"sendmail_path";s:18:"/usr/sbin/sendmail";s:13:"sendmail_args";s:2:"-i";s:10:"smtpServer";s:46:"ssl://mysmtpserver.net";s:8:"smtpPort";s:3:"465";s:8:"smtpAuth";s:1:"1";s:12:"smtpUsername";s:23:"info@...com";s:12:"smtpPassword";s:44:"XXX";}

Comment: also when I press save and sent test mail, the message is positive and the test mail is succesfully sent, also the page still shows the settings
---
Once I reload the page or navigate to it again through the menu, the settings are gone

Comment: Hi @Marc, is the above entry complete? Your fragment does not show the field "smtpServer". That is the field that is checked when the error is raised.

Comment: Hey @Kainuk, yes, sorry, here is the complete vale from the DB:
`
a:10:{s:5:"qfKey";s:36:"1af2b96d179c0382dd8d12784ee0d7b9_137";s:8:"entryURL";s:134:"http://www.maydomain.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&amp;task=civicrm/admin/setting/smtp&amp;option=com_civicrm&amp;reset=1";s:15:"outBound_option";s:1:"0";s:13:"sendmail_path";s:18:"/usr/sbin/sendmail";s:13:"sendmail_args";s:2:"-i";s:10:"smtpServer";s:46:"ssl://mysmtpserver.com";s:8:"smtpPort";s:3:"465";s:8:"smtpAuth";s:1:"1";s:12:"smtpUsername";s:23:"info@maydomain.com";s:12:"smtpPassword";s:44:"mypassword";}`

Comment: Edit: seems like I cant put the entire string as special characters cause it to look cut like that. But the entire SMTP information is present

Comment: ...s:15:"outBound_option";s:1:"0";s:13:"sendmail_path";s:18:"/usr/sbin/sendmail";s:13:"sendmail_args";s:2:"-i";s:10:"smtpServer";s:46:"ssl://mysmtpserver.com";s:8:"smtpPort";s:3:"465";s:8:"smtpAuth";s:1:"1";s:12:"smtpUsername";s:23:"info@maydomain.com";s:12:"smtpPassword";s:44:"mypassword";}

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a caching problem. I recently had the [same issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18207?focusedCommentId=98816&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-98816).

Comment: Checked demo site(s), both Drupal and Joomla set `Expires` header in the past and `Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate` when viewing CMS and CRM admin pages. Suggests there really is an issue with jSGCache caching when it should not ... Wasn't able to find source of jSGCache plugin to confirm though.

Answer (score 0):

If runInNonProductionEnvironment=TRUE, then the mailing settings are coming from 'mailing_backend_store' in stead of 'mailing_backend' in the table civicrm_setting. You need to modify it manually in the table.