# How to get more debug info about "DB Error: no such field Return to home page"

Tags: wordpress, error, database

I have created an event registration form, using a profile with a custom field. When I click `Continue` after filling in the form, I see `Processing ...` and then I get the confirmation screen, which looks good. But when I hit `Continue` I get:

```
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: no such field Return to home page.
```

WordPress 4.7.4
CiviCRM 4.7.17

I'm filling in two of the input fields from URL variables.  Not sure if that might be a problem.

If you want to try:

https://connectionpractice.org/test-webinar-with-affiliate-code/?affiliatecode=irthlingz1&eventtype=Introduction

I'm thinking I need to get more debug info to figure out which field is causing the problem.  How can I do that?

P.S. My code for the URL variables

```
<script>
(function($) {
  // all JS code here
var l = document.location;
  var affiliatecode = l.search.match(/affiliatecode=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/)[1];
var eventtype = l.search.match(/eventtype=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/)[1];
   $( "input#custom_3").val(affiliatecode);
   $( "input#event_type").val(eventtype);
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways.
First, you can enable debugging and backtrace under **Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**.

The same information should be available in your ConfigAndLog directory.  See [Where are the "ConfigAndLog" and "templates_c" directories?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)