# Contributions: Error Cancelling Contribution The recurring contribution could not be cancelled

Tags: civicontribute

When our users go to the cancel contribution link in their confirmation email and select "Cancel Contribution" they get the following error: Error Cancelling Contribution The recurring contribution could not be cancelled.

Furthermore, if I am logged in and try the same link, I am able to cancel to contribution, but only if I deselect "Send cancellation request to PayPal Pro ?". Otherwise I get the same error.

Any ideas?

CiviCRM 4.7.14 / Drupal 7.53

Comment: This is a good question!  To solve your problem, we'll need to see the debugging info.  In CiviCRM, go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save". Repeat the steps that caused your error, and you'll see much a more detailed error. Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debug/backtrace when you're done! You can also get this info from the log located in the [ConfigAndLog directory](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/15931/12)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I enabled debugging and backtrace before.
When I repeat the action I get no entries in the CiviCRM.6e9bf2327d44a5335eb442c8.log logfile.
However, there is a correpsonding entry in Drupal's dblog:
Notice: Undefined index: payment_processor_type in CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl->cancelSubscription() (line 663 of /var/www/html/sitename/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're describing is a known bug, which is documented at [CRM-20800](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20800).  A patch was submitted yesterday; by testing this patch, you can speed its inclusion into an upcoming version of CiviCRM.