# DB Error under Languages, Currency, Location

Tags: joomla, localisation

We need some help we using CiviCRM version 4.7.20 on Joomla version 3.7.2 and I try to set up the German languages, with no success:
On **Administer – Localization – Languages, Currency, Location** this message appears:

**Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.**

---

**DB Error: insufficient permissions
Return to home page.**

Thanks in advance for your support.

```
#0 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: insufficient permissions", -26, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...")
#3 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-26, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...")
#4 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -26, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-26, NULL, NULL, "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...", "1142 ** TRIGGER command denied to user 'db12382598-user5'@'localhost' for tab...")
#7 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...")
#9 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...")
#10 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): DB_DataObject->_query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...")
#11 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(362): DB_DataObject->query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...")
#12 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1940): CRM_Core_DAO->query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EAC...")
#13 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Localization.php(88): CRM_Core_DAO::checkTriggerViewPermission(TRUE)
#14 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(564): CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Localization->buildQuickForm()
#15 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#16 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Localization), "display")
#17 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Localization), "display")
#18 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#19 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#20 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(283): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Localization", "Languages, Currency, Locations", (Array:0))
#21 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#22 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#23 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#24 /web/_crm/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#25 /web/_crm/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(394): require_once("/web/_crm/administrator/comp...")
#26 /web/_crm/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(369): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/web/_crm/administrator/comp...")
#27 /web/_crm/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(98): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#28 /web/_crm/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(156): JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch()
#29 /web/_crm/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(265): JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute()
#30 /web/_crm/administrator/index.php(51): JApplicationCms->execute()
#31 {main}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your CiviCRM version?  This was a bug a few versions back that's since been fixed.

Comment: Additionally, we may need to see the debugging info.  In CiviCRM, go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save". Repeat the steps that caused your error, and you'll see much a more detailed error. Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debug/backtrace when you're done! You can also get this info from the log located in the [ConfigAndLog directory](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/15931/12)

Comment: Hi William, thanks for our repley. We use the newest version of joomla and Civicrm that i downloaded on the offical sites.

Comment: It´s looks like there is a DB and Pear script error :/

Answer (score 2):

The important part of the log is this:

```
TRIGGER command denied to user 'db12382598-user5'@'localhost'
```

You need to grant the TRIGGER permission to the MySQL user named above.  Note that if you're on crappy shared hosting, you might not be allowed to use database triggers, which CiviCRM requires.

You can find more info here: [CiviCRM MySQL Permission Requirements](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+MySQL+Permission+Requirements)