# Exporting Contacts Results in DB Error

Tags: contacts, export

I am trying to export about 2000 contacts (exporting primary fields only) and when I click continue I get this error:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error:
>   unknown error Return to home page.

Not sure why its occurring and how to find out more info?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KarinG's answer is correct.  To anticipate what you're likely to find - when you do an export, CiviCRM generates a temporary database table.  Many servers aren't configured with a large enough space in their `/tmp` directory to store a large database table.  Because "all primary fields" is actually a very large number of fields, you're likely overwhelming the temporary space.

I recommend selecting only the fields you need rather than all primary fields, and this issue is likely to go away.  Alternatively, increase the size of your `/tmp` folder.

Answer (score 2):

First place to look is in the [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) directory - it will contain a number of files. Find the current log file; it will contain more details on the DB Error (if you can't easily find it -> reproduce your DB error by trying to export again -> then the DB error will be at the bottom of the current log file).