# Paypal Payment Processor not connecting with CiviCRM

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paypal

We used the Paypal Pro Payment Processor with Civi. It has worked well in the past (including last month). After the last update they are no longer working properly. However, the payment processor is taking the actual payment.

For example I went through our donation page and donated $1.11. On hitting submit I received this error
[image]
On the CiviCRM End I received this error failing to update database.
[image]
However, on the Paypal end the payment went through. I received a notification from Paypal indicating I received a donation of $1.11.

So, something is happening on the Civi end of things but I don't know how to fix this error.

Here are the errors:

```
CRM_Core_Exception: Failed to update contribution in database in /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php on line 2336
Exception trace
#
Function
Location

0
CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->completeTransaction(Array, 99)
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php:2336
1
CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processFormSubmission('6')
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php:716
2
CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->postProcess()
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:447
3
CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php:1314
4
CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main->skipToThankYouPage()
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php:1048
5
CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main->postProcess()
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:447
6
CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:169
7
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main), 'upload')
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:136
8
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main), 'upload')
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
9
HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main), 'upload')
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
10
HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('upload')
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:351
11
CRM_Core_Controller->run(Array, null)
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:310
12
CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:84
13
CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:52
14
CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:448
15
civicrm_invoke('contribute', 'transact')
unknown:unknown
16
call_user_func_array('civicrm_invoke', Array)
/var/www/html/includes/menu.inc:527
17
menu_execute_active_handler()
/var/www/html/index.php:21
18
{main}

 Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.Failed to update contribution in database
Return to home page.
```

Comment: Check the CiviCRM log in the ConfigAndLog directory for clues; Something goes wrong when yoir Contribution is trying to write to the database

Comment: To expand on KarinG's comment: To solve your problem, we'll need to see the debugging info. In CiviCRM, go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save". Repeat the steps that caused your error, and you'll see much a more detailed error. Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debug/backtrace afterward! You can also get this info from the log located in the [ConfigAndLog directory](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/15931/12)

Comment: Thanks for guiding me through the how-to on the Debugging.

Comment: There is normally an "edit" link underneath the question, just underneath the tags.
One thing to check re the "no such field" error: do you have Civi advanced logging enabled (at /civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1)? If so, possibly a field has failed to be added to one of the logging tables. Try /civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1 or disable then re-enable logging.

Comment: Thanks for the backtrace!  From the backtrace, it looks like you do NOT have a confirmation page - once you submit the contribution, it goes straight to "Thank You".  As a test, could you try enabling the confirmation page and see if the problem goes away?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

It turns out that the CiviCRM logs contained error messages that indicated a missing database column, specifically a CiviCRM custom field. It's not clear why the column was missing, and the CiviCRM admin continued to display the field. An attempt to edit and save the custom field, in the CiviCRM admin, resulted in the same error as occured when submitting the donation form, which appeared to confirm that the custom field was the culprit. Sure enough, once this column was rebuilt, the problem was solved.