# Relationships not visible after migrating from Wordpress to Drupal

Tags: drupal, relationships, core

I have migrated a CIVICRm installation from Wordpress to Drupal. Everything is working except the relationship tab under contacts.
The tab heading has the number of relationships but no relationships are visible. 
[image: contact tab]

Also I can see the relationship in the relationship report.

How do I fix this as there no error being logged

Thanks

Comment: Did you migrate the relationships?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and the resolution was to ensure that the URL you use to access Drupal and CiviCRM must be consistent with what's entered in the CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL in civicrm.settings.php and the Resource URL in Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Resource URLs.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with `templates_c`.  Try deleting the `templates_c` folder: [Where are the "ConfigAndLog" and "templates_c" directories?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)