# Contact field, DB Error: no such field

Tags: wordpress, contacts

So I just updated CiviCRM to 5.0 and I keep getting the error DB Error: no such field when I try and view/edit a contact. It doesn't allow me to view any contact but I can search and find my contacts. I am not sure what is going on but this happened even before I upgraded Civi and it was 4.7.

Comment: Can you look at or post the relevant part from the CiviCRM log that says which field this is talking about (file location described here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)?

Comment: Apr 10 20:25:19  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -19
    [message] => DB Error: no such field
    [mode] => 16
Here is an instance where it happened.

Comment: Any extensions being used?

Comment: Caldera Forms CiviCRM is the only one Ive used in the past week that resulted in this error.

Comment: Is there more in the log, where it shows the actual SQL statement that would indicate the field name?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It's a legit question just maybe missing details, and he/she took the time to post a followup answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that it was a bad custom field in my data set, when I disabled the set I can view my contacts. Thank you everyone who helped me with this.

Comment: Cant accept my answer apparently so sorry if it is unresolved still.

Comment: Your answer is just as unhelpful as the question. How did you disable the data set with bad custom field?