# Live links are not working for Events

Tags: civievent, links

I am using Joomla 3.8.8 stable and CiviCRM 4.7.25 New or copied live event and payment links are being redirected to the homepage. Existing events work and go to forms.

Comment: Could you please provide us with more information?  When you say "not working", what happens? Is there an error message? A blank white screen? Is there any message in the CiviCRM log?

Comment: Joomla is a subfolder on our hosting site and civiCRM is installed in the Joomla folder. the link is https://www.greatlakeswbc.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=77 and the test link is https://www.greatlakeswbc.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&action=preview&id=70

Comment: Here is a older link that is working: https://www.greatlakeswbc.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=66

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  As a Q&A site, it's not really set up for the back-and-forth discussion you're doing in comments, so I can't really read your error - it's not formatted.  If you could edit your original question to contain this information, it will be much easier to read and respond to.  Also, check out https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour for a 90-second guide to getting the best answers from this site.

Comment: I guess the basic trouble shooting steps you should look at are updating to the latest CiviCRM version & evaluating what extensions & custom code you are using (& potentially updating any extensions or experimenting with turning them off & seeing if the issue persists).

Also finding & checking log files

Answer (score 1):

When I click your links I can see that the "bad" link returns a 302 redirect - but the "good" link does not.  I would review your CiviCRM log (in [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/12) for an error that appears when someone hits the bad link.