# Missing Custom Activity Field Data When the Activity is Filed on a Case.

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, civicase

As the title states. Data that I enter into custom activity fields, is saved and

I can view that saved data from the Activities tab in the Contact Summary.

Like this:

[image: Data Fields are Populated when viewed from Contact Summary]

But after the activity is filed on a case most of the data fields appear empty when the data is viewed from within CiviCase.

[image: Data Fields in the same Custom Activity Type are empty when filed on a case]

These fields were working fine up until I updated the system to 5.4. It continues after I updated to CiviCRM 5.5.1. on WP version 4.9.8.

How can I troubleshoot/fix this error? I am not able to duplicate this issue on the demo system found at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/.

Not sure if it is related but I'm not able to create a Public Profile to share as that is getting an error, "Identity is invalid, Certificate is Expired".

Answer (score 1):

First check the log files ([Where are the "ConfigAndLog" and "templates_c" directories?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)) and see if there's anything obvious happening there.

Otherwise if you can debug in CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php in the copyExtendedActivityData() function that should help track it down. That's the function that gets called from _convertToCaseActivity() in CRM/Case/Page/AJAX.php to copy the custom data and attachments.

Comment: I checked those folders and didn't see anything related to this activity/process. 

I did notice that if under the custom field>Edit Field> the option "
View Only?  Is this field set by PHP code (via a custom hook). This field will not be updated by CiviCRM." If that field is checked then those fields do not pass data thru to the case activity. I tested with a new entry and can confirm that all of the editable fields are going thru.

Prior to the update to 5.4-5.5.1 all of the fields would pass thru to the case regardless if that option was checked or not.

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying a lot of the fields you collect are actually computed by some custom code and not directly editable?

Comment: The fields I had as "View Only" were populated via Caldera Forms using the Caldera Forms CiviCRM plugin to bring that data into Civi's custom fields. The fields are now transferring fine once I unchecked the "View Only" option for the data fields. So for now I have a work around but I'd like to be able to make those fields view only eventually.