# Fatal Error when accessing Civi in WP Install

Tags: wordpress, cache

My Civi seems to be broken, and I'm really unsure why! This is the error I receive when trying to open the base CiviCRM homepage.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Invalid cache key: Not a string thrown in /home2/snachodo/public_html/boyscoutstech/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Cache.php on line 221
```

Can anyone point to a resource to resolve the error?

A further complication that I didn't realize until this week is that I am unable to create new blog posts or pages in WordPress. I receive the same error as above. However, WordPress works when I deactivate CiviCRM as a plugin.

Log message below:

```
[22-Dec-2018 00:25:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface' not found in /home2/snachodo/public_html/boyscoutstech/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Cache/Interface.php on line 40
[22-Dec-2018 00:47:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface' not found in /home2/snachodo/public_html/boyscoutstech/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Cache/Interface.php on line 40
[22-Dec-2018 22:29:32 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  Declaration of CRM_Mailchimp_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home2/snachodo/public_html/boyscoutstech/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/CRM/Mailchimp/Permission.php on line 40
[22-Dec-2018 22:29:38 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  Declaration of CRM_Mailchimp_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home2/snachodo/public_html/boyscoutstech/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/CRM/Mailchimp/Permission.php on line 40
[22-Dec-2018 23:15:00 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  Declaration of CRM_Mailchimp_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home2/snachodo/public_html/boyscoutstech/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/CRM/Mailchimp/Permission.php on line 40
[03-Jan-2019 09:02:18 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  Declaration of CRM_Mailchimp_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home2/snachodo/public_html/boyscoutstech/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/CRM/Mailchimp/Permission.php on line 40
```

Comment: WP version 5.0.2
CiviCRM version 5.5.0 according to the release-notes.md

Comment: When I say base CiviCRM homepage I mean [URL]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM

Comment: Can you give any details of what's happened before this? Are you in the process of installing or is it a live site that was working recently? Were you working on the site/making changes? Also, do you have access to the MySQL tables?

Comment: Have you tried clearing caches? ie. [URL]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM/clearcache

Comment: @RoseLanigan it is a live site. It was working one day, and then this error came up the next. Didn't do anything specifically fancy that I'm aware of that would have caused the error.

I do have access to the tables, but I am not well versed in MySQL.

Comment: @MatthewWire just attempted to clear the cache at the URL and I receive an access error: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

It appears to be a Civi error (as in, it looks like the Civi styling)

Comment: @william-mortada I see you added installation as a tag. This CiviCRM site has been installed and actively used for about 7 months, so I can't imagine it's an installation related issue

Comment: You may want to check the [CiviCRM logs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) for a full backtrace which can give us a clue.  Maybe you have an alternate cache (e.g. Redis) defined?  Please edit your question with the full backtrace and hopefully we can help!

Comment: @SteveDogiakos ah, okay.  Apologies for that.  I see that Pete has removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the log message suggests you've hit a limit of your hosting provider.

> User snachodo_657 already has more than 'max_user_connections'

This could have various causes. If your hosting plan only allows a certain number of DB connections simultaneously and your site creates more than that, you'd see this.

I don't think it's a common issue for CiviCRM so it may be that the hosting provider has a low number of permitted DB connections, OR that your site is busier than most sites on your hosting provider.

It's worth noting that CiviCRM's DB connection methodology does not re-use Wordpress's DB connection, so for any visitor on a CiviCRM page, your site will consume two DB connections at once.

In the first case, I'd contact your hosting provider and enquire about the limit. It might be a config tweak they can make, or they may offer you a plan with more DB connections.

If that doesn't work out, you could ask an expert to investigate why your site is making too many connections, or look into [hosting providers who provide support for CiviCRM sites](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country_1=All&services=Hosting&language=All&cms=All).

Hope that's some help!

Comment: I've changed the info I got from the error log to a possibly more relevant section. I wasn't having trouble with any of the other sites hosted on this server.