# "This site can't be reached" error message when trying to

Tags: civimail

I got the above error message when trying to print mailing labels. I have here a screen cap of the entire message and I'd appreciate it if you could please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error is unfortunately not enough information to go on.  I would suggest checking your [CiviCRM log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) and perhaps your web server's error log as well.

If I had to hazard a guess though - it's possible that some element of your Joomla theme is adding text (perhaps a header or footer) to every page - and this is causing the PDF to be incorrectly formatted.  If that's the case, you should see this same error when you print any PDF.