# Recurring Payment Profile IPNs not Updating CiviCRM with new Transactions

Tags: webform-civicrm, paypal, recurring-contributions, ipn

Environment:

- CiviCRM 5.5.x is the version that created the ones that are now trying to update, but we are now on the latest version 5.11.00
  Drupal 7.x
- Webform CiviCRM 7.x-4.20+16-dev

Issue:

The first payment made via Webform CiviCRM with 4 1-year terms (Annual) is correctly made in CiviCRM with the payment profile created successfully in Paypal Website Payment Pro. One year after the original transaction, an IPN appears to be sent back from Paypal WPP (copied below) but there is no change on the CiviCRM Recurring Contribution to show the transaction.

Suggestions? Can someone triage this as a Webform CiviCRM issue, CiviCRM bug, or Paypal WPP issue?

At first, I thought the IPN wasn't sending, so I ran the Civi upgrade to 5.11.00 and had Paypal resend the IPN. I checked the CiviCRM System Log table and found the IPN there. The contribution record, however, shows no update.

IPN log:

"{"amount":"100.00","initial_payment_amount":"0.00","profile_status":"Active","payer_id":"E42LJNE93RWRS","product_type":"1","ipn_track_id":"ea7354b7cadf0","outstanding_balance":"0.00","shipping":"0.00","charset":"windows-1252","period_type":" Regular","payment_gross":"100.00","currency_code":"USD","receipt_id":"1095-1202-0757-8493","verify_sign":"ARTWVaUGckuviK6HZ-Of6l88vDtdApgb5SsBR5toeMzYD61j13z0iSqX","payment_cycle":"Yearly","txn_type":"recurring_payment","receiver_id":"XBC22BNDGX5QA","payment_fee":"3.00","mc_currency":"USD","transaction_subject":"Webform Payment: 100 Per 1 year","protection_eligibility":"Ineligible","payer_status":"unverified","first_name":"First","product_name":"Webform Payment: : 100 Per 1 year","amount_per_cycle":"100.00","mc_gross":"100.00","payment_date":"04:11:20 Mar 04, 2019 PST","rp_invoice_id":"i=287cdb784fe4fcdd731906c53e048cdc&m=contribute&c=4729&r=178&b=&p=","payment_status":"Completed","business":"ouremail@ourdomain","last_name":"Last","txn_id":"6EH773960F7425301","mc_fee":"3.00","time_created":"16:30:53 Mar 04, 2018 PST","resend":"true","payment_type":"instant","notify_version":"3.8","recurring_payment_id":"I-1PBATXDD4H0C","payer_email":"client@email.com","receiver_email":"ouremail@ourdomain.com","next_payment_date":"02:00:00 Mar 04, 2020 PST","tax":"0.00","residence_country":"US"}"

My rationale for posting it here is I'm not sure where the issue lies so I am happy to report/test anything needed to clear it up.

[image: The Recurring series in CiviCRM the above IPN should update]

Update 3/19/2019 - on the latest version of Civi and Webform CiviCRM I created a new recurring profile of $1.00/day and it successfully processed in Paypal each time. CiviCRM only has a record of the first transaction and is receiving the IPN's for the followups but is not doing anything with them. Here are some IPN below (edited for privacy)

The cancellation from Paypal did not cancel anything in Civi:

{"payment_cycle":"Daily","txn_type":"recurring_payment_profile_cancel","last_name":"last","next_payment_date":"N/A","residence_country":"US","initial_payment_amount":"0.00","rp_invoice_id":"i=c83d98a31d0e2c2a5cf3173493e24e3b&m=contribute&c=16014&r=830&b=&p=","currency_code":"USD","time_created":"14:16:08 Mar 14, 2019 PDT","verify_sign":"AyT1wi4GzlURUfQbTmQWfTBcmyeoAgAjHAleKj2b1QyzJd-.4gNAHVEt","period_type":" Regular","payer_status":"unverified","tax":"0.00","payer_email":"payee@email.com","first_name":"first","receiver_email":"ouremail@.com","payer_id":"S5E6YRTVCSZTQ","product_type":"1","shipping":"0.00","amount_per_cycle":"1.00","profile_status":"Cancelled","charset":"windows-1252","notify_version":"3.9","amount":"1.00","outstanding_balance":"0.00","recurring_payment_id":"I-F4WEDCKXYUFS","product_name":"Webform Payment","ipn_track_id":"c7efd7f383b01"}

One of the Payment notices did not create a Contribution in Civi:

{"mc_gross":"1.00","period_type":" Regular","outstanding_balance":"0.00","next_payment_date":"03:00:00 Mar 19, 2019 PDT","protection_eligibility":"Ineligible","payment_cycle":"Daily","tax":"0.00","payer_id":"S5E6YRTVCSZTQ","payment_date":"05:09:39 Mar 18, 2019 PDT","payment_status":"Completed","product_name":"Webform Payment: Membership Forms Debugging Page: 1 Per 1 day","charset":"windows-1252","rp_invoice_id":"i=c83d98a31d0e2c2a5cf3173493e24e3b&m=contribute&c=16014&r=830&b=&p=","recurring_payment_id":"I-F4WEDCKXYUFS","first_name":"first","mc_fee":"0.33","notify_version":"3.9","amount_per_cycle":"1.00","payer_status":"unverified","currency_code":"USD","business":"our@account.com","verify_sign":"AFgGSSN7T0eV820ZsLG2eXpvjHjxA2u3dUQBLcGbSQLiJfOaSXghKIV-","payer_email":"payee@email.com","initial_payment_amount":"0.00","profile_status":"Active","amount":"1.00","txn_id":"5489090059341273U","payment_type":"instant","last_name":"last","receiver_email":"ouraccount@.com","payment_fee":"0.33","receiver_id":"XBC22BNDGX5QA","txn_type":"recurring_payment","mc_currency":"USD","residence_country":"US","receipt_id":"5598-9968-4788-6393","transaction_subject":"Webform Payment","payment_gross":"1.00","shipping":"0.00","product_type":"1","time_created":"14:16:08 Mar 14, 2019 PDT","ipn_track_id":"195d7793815d3"}

Edit 2: I've installed https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.notificationlog and retried an IPN that failed with a backtrace. Any thoughts?

```
drush cvapi NotificationLog.retry system_log_id=12638 debug=1
PayPalFailure: Missing Parameter b                                                                                                                          [error]
Array
(
    [trace] => #0 /myserver/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php(436): CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalProIPN->getValue('b', true)
#1 /myserver/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm_extensions/nz.co.fuzion.notificationlog-master/api/v3/NotificationLog/Retry.php(75): CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalProIPN->main()
#2 /myserver/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm_extensions/nz.co.fuzion.notificationlog-master/api/v3/NotificationLog/Retry.php(24): _civicrm_api3_notification_log_process(Array)
#3 /myserver/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(100): civicrm_api3_notification_log_retry(Array)
#4 /myserver/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(169): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke(Array)
#5 /myserver/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Array)
#6 /myserver/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe('NotificationLog', 'retry', Array, NULL)
#7 /myserver/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/drush/civicrm.drush.inc(1558): civicrm_api('NotificationLog', 'retry', Array)
#8 [internal function]: drush_civicrm_api('NotificationLog...', 'system_log_id=1...', 'debug=1')
#9 /usr/share/php/drush/includes/command.inc(334): call_user_func_array('drush_civicrm_a...', Array)
#10 /usr/share/php/drush/includes/command.inc(208): _drush_invoke_hooks('civicrm-api', Array, 'civicrm')
#11 [internal function]: drush_command('NotificationLog...', 'system_log_id=1...', 'debug=1')
#12 /usr/share/php/drush/includes/command.inc(175): call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#13 /usr/share/php/drush/drush.php(92): drush_dispatch(Array)
#14 /usr/share/php/drush/drush.php(61): _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#15 /usr/share/php/drush/drush.php(16): drush_main()
#16 {main}
    [is_error] => 1
    [error_message] => Failure: Missing Parameter b
)
```

Comment: Has the contact's Civi ID changed?  Is the Paypal account exactly the same as a year ago?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. Are you suggesting a merged contact (or something) may cause this? In the above example the cid = 4729 in CiviCRM which seems to match the IPN. I do not know of any major changes to the Paypal account.

Comment: There might have been a change in the Paypal IPN URL? Could that be the culprit? It doesn't seem like it, because Civi still has the IPN's in its logs.

Comment: Do you have other recurring transactions posting successfully?  Or are they all failing?  You might try setting up a recurring contribution directly in Civi (perhaps with a week duration, so you don't have to wait a whole year to see if it works, LOL) and see if that posts correctly.

Comment: good ideas, will report back. differentiating between regular civicontribute and ones created by webform civicrm is also needed.

Comment: I now have a recurring contribution for $1/day set up through Webform CiviCRM it created the Paypal WPS profile correctly, at 2PM tomorrow I'll know if its working for new ones.

Comment: This one did not create a transaction either. I'm on the most up to date stable webform civicrm and civicrm.

Comment: Have you seen [civicrm-core#659](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/659) in CiviCRM's Gitlab? Some debugging steps there may help.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBurgess I posted in that thread an Eileen thought it was a separate issue. I added some more details in the OP.

Comment: I am noticing that native Civi recurring transactions to Paypal WPP come back with the Transaction ID on the recurring profile in civi, but ones made via Webform CiviCRM do not - could that explain it?

Comment: Good odds it was a separate issue (esp if Eileen says so!), just thought the steps to debug from that thread might be useful to you, eg inspecting CiviCRM's debug logs ... And it's often useful to know about other / similar bugs ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When troubleshooting IPNs, the most important first step is to see if CiviCRM received them correctly.  You can do this by checking the `civicrm_system_log` database table for the IPNs.

If you are NOT receiving the IPNs in Civi, there is most likely a web server configuration error, or they're being sent to the wrong URL.

If Civi IS receiving the IPNs, you can use the excellent [notificationlog](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.notificationlog) extension to replay your IPNs.  On replay, you can check your [CiviCRM logs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/12) for errors, insert debugging code, etc.

Comment: I updated the OP with the debug from the notificationlog extension.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it seems like the most generic and plausible way for another person in my spot to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

My answer above is generic to this issue; this answer is specifically addressing Zachary.  Thanks for posting the backtrace, it's got the details we need.

When you create an ARB (recurring payment) subscription with PayPal, Civi sends some details to PayPal.  In return, PayPal embeds those details in every IPN.  That's how Civi can match an IPN with the correct contact, membership, etc.

In the last IPN above, it's this part:

```
"rp_invoice_id":"i=c83d98a31d0e2c2a5cf3173493e24e3b&m=contribute&c=16014&r=830&b=&p="
```

Note that there are no values for `b` or `p`.  Your error, not coincidentally, is `Missing Parameter b`. I have a [Troubleshooting PayPal and CiviCRM](https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/Troubleshooting_PayPal_and_CiviCRM#In-PayPal) page on my wiki that says what each letter is for.  That [same information is available](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php#L432-L453) in the file in line `#0` in your backtrace.

I can see there that `p` is OK to be blank.  However, the value of `b` is supposed to be the contribution ID of the first contribution made as part of this recurring series.  If you look at my wiki page linked above, you can read how to fix this.  You only need to a) look up the appropriate contribution ID; b) add it in PayPal using the instruction in the *In PayPal* section of the wiki.

That explains how to fix the existing payments that exist!  The question that remains is how this happened in the first place.  For that, I can't help you; I haven't seen this before.  However, I also have no sites running PayPal Pro AND Webform-CiviCRM, so that's a clue.  You may want to try to replicate this through webform; very likely though, it's something that was fixed a while ago and you just need to clean up the mess.

PS - to fix IPNs that you can't resend from PayPal, you can also edit the `b=` value in `civicrm_system_log` and use the `notificationlog` extension to replay those successfully.

Comment: On all the latest versions so we'll see what happens. Appreciate you walking me through this!

Answer (score 0):

Our team ran into a similar issue. Check the permissions on your server. They may have changed after you updated Civi.

Comment: Thanks for being part of CiviCRM's Stackexchange! This answer could be a lot more informative if it was more detailed? "Permissions" could mean filesystem permissions, CMS permissions, DB permissions, or something else entirely ...

Comment: The issue happened before and after the upgrade, but I am open to all suggestions!