# "System Status: Error" I updated to CiviCRM 5.12.0 hosted on WordPress internally on a QNAP TS-251+ Server. Where do I go from here?

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, civicrm.settings.php

```
System Status: Error
Cron Not Running (CiviCRM Homepage says "Loading...)
Configure Default Mailbox (CiviCRM Homepage says "Loading...)
Complete Setup (CiviCRM Homepage says "Loading...)
MySQL utf8mb4 Support (Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8))
PHP Out-of-Date (Unavoidable)
Remote Profiles Enabled (CiviCRM Homepage says "Loading...)
View details and manage alerts
```

I know why the PHP is out of date. QNAP refuses to update their firmware.
We use PHPMyadmin.

I see suggestions aiming at editing this or that, but don't know what to use to edit.
We are hosting internally and I setup everything, but I do not know how to restore the settings and database. I am adept at searching through folders and putting preconfigured pieces in place, but this is like thinking 4 moves ahead in chess for me. I struggle at 3.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the php version? And it's not really clear what you're stuck on - is it that the hompage just says "loading" and stays like that? If so check the civicrm log for errors. See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/181 for how to find it. Also check the web server logs..

Comment: Actually none of those are errors, those are warnings usually civicrm give asking to make some configurations. If you go to click on civicrm from your dashboard menu, does civi UI not open up?

Comment: I have the CiviCRM updated to 5.12.1, I can now access the CiviCRM Home. The QNAP TS-251+ runs PHP version: 5.6.38. It is hardwired in the firmware.

Currently System Status: Error

I do not currently have access to our cases. Names, contact info, cases and activities are all gone.
I have a feeling it is hiding somewhere, but CiviCRM is not aimed at it. It is like a fresh install with My info and "Default Organization" only. Where is our information? How do I point it to our year of work database of 700+ clients?

Again, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the civicrm.settings.php is pointing to your civicrm database containing all your data ? You should go to phpMyAdmin (do a full backup if not already done), check which database have your contact (civicrm_contact should have 700+ lines) and use this one in civicrm.settings.php.

Comment: I checked PHPMyadmin and the database we were using is gone. We are resigned to rebuilding the database. We are setting a volume timeline backup and a weekly manual backup of PHPMyadmin. Is there a way to automate the PHPMyadmin backup? I have a hard time believing that something so mission critical is not backed up in any other way than manual.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used a QNAP for this, but have in other contexts. You might be able to install entware ( https://www.qnapclub.eu/en/qpkg/556 ) and use that to install php7.1 or similar QPKG from entware's repo

Answer (score 0):

I have learned a lot about CiviCRM and I almost have it working. I followed so many directions that I am not sure where it got to the point that it is. I will post another question, since I am past this issue.