# How to cure empty config screens in civi?

Tags: custom-fields, civisurvey

We are getting two Civi config screens which show a header, but no content. The screen loads but is empty - no options, no fields, no instructions.

One is when wanting to delete a custom field -
[here's a video of what happens](https://www.loom.com/share/78dee12c14204ddfbdbcfd4dcd4d1baf)

One is on the Results tab when wanting to set up a Survey -
[image: Results tab in Survey config]

Any ideas how to cure this?

CiviCRM 5.1.2 Drupal 7.67

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem with your compiled templates - try deleting templates_c.  You can do this [in-app](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#symptoms), or [manually](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories).

That said, templates_c errors are often indicative of a misconfiguration (most commonly, that your cron jobs don't run as the webserver user) so it's likely you'll need to delete manually because the webserver user lacks permission to delete the template in question.  If this problem recurs, you'll want to identify its root cause.