# Error Message when trying to validate Batch data entry

Tags: contributions, batches

I keep attempting to validate a batch data entry and keep receiving this error message:

"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: unknown error
Return to home page."

Has anyone had this happen to them? Any help would be appreciated!

Edits: Here is the error message in full
ml/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(192): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()

## 1 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))

## 2 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , payment_in...")

## 3 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , payment_in...")

## 4 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , payment_in...", "DB_Error", TRUE)

## 5 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))

## 6 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , payment_in...", "1205 ** Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction")

## 7 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()

## 8 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , payment_in...")

## 9 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , payment_in...")

## 10 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1040): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , payment_in...")

## 11 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(572): DB_DataObject->insert()

## 12 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php(231): CRM_Core_DAO->save()

## 13 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php(502): CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::add((Array:29), (Array:0))

## 14 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Batch/Form/Entry.php(566): CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::create((Array:29))

## 15 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Batch/Form/Entry.php(427): CRM_Batch_Form_Entry->processContribution((Array:11))

## 16 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(490): CRM_Batch_Form_Entry->postProcess()

## 17 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(169): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()

## 18 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(136): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Batch_Form_Entry), "upload")

## 19 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Batch_Form_Entry), "upload")

## 20 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Batch_Form_Entry), "upload")

## 21 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/extensions/biz.jmaconsulting.grantapplications/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("upload")

## 22 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(114): CRM_Core_Controller->run()

## 23 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(284): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Batch_Form_Entry", NULL, (Array:0))

## 24 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))

## 25 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

## 26 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1392): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

## 27 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")

## 28 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))

## 29 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))

## 30 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(253): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")

Comment: Can you locate the log file (see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) and edit your question to include the fuller error message listed in the log file?

Comment: The directions to locate the log file aren't very clear to me.

Comment: Ok you can try turning on the debug settings as described at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#using-the-built-in-debugging-tools, and then do the batch validate, and you should see the full errors on the screen. Then make sure to turn off the setting after.

Comment: Thanks! The error code is too long to fit into these comments but here's the first: ml/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(192): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /home/mrg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))

There were over 25 lines of error messages.

Comment: If you edit the original question it might paste better.

Comment: It's a database lock timeout but it's not obvious why. Two things you can try: 1. Temporarily disable the Grant Applications extension and see if that fixes it. 2. If you're on a recent version there's a setting in civicrm.settings.php that might help: `define('CIVICRM_SUPPORT_MULTIPLE_LOCKS', TRUE);`