# WordPress Contribution Page Submission Not Working

Tags: wordpress

I have a web site hosted on IIS (6.2) with PHP 7.1.3 with WP 5.2.3 and Civicrm 5.17.4. My contribution forms are not submitting (it does not proceed to the confirmation page or get actually submitted). To clear off that it is not My Theme or the Other plugins that are playing up, I have installed a fresh copy of WP / Civicrm and used the WP 2019 default theme and created a sample contribution form to test.

The test form does not work either. Already tried resetting cache and paths and providing more rights to the web folder. Anyone else facing the same issue or if able to help will highly appreciate!

Comment: Do you have any payment processor enabled on the page? or only pay later?

Comment: For this fresh install to test, I have set Pay Later. However in the actual site I have payment enabled but that too does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your [Civicrm logs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/15931/12)? Would be the best place to start.  See what civicrm is complaining about.