# DB Error: constraint violation (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, error, php7

I am trying to update an install from CiviCRM version 4.4.5 to the current version.

I was unable to because the WordPress site was using PHP 5.6.

So I installed CiviCRM 4.7.31, and then updated the server to PHP 7.0.

Now when I click the CiviCRM menu link in the dashboard, I get this:

DB Error: constraint violation

[image]

Comment: Find your civicrm error log (see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) and inside the file there will be a more detailed error. If you think it will require some back and forth, then https://chat.civicrm.org is a better place for that.

Answer (score 1):

Aaron welcome to stack exchange, Can you logout and login again? If its a new install than you contact id might have not set properly in session.

Comment: I have tried that. No progress. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: can you check civicrm error log to find more details of db error?