# Issue with submitting forms - blank page

Tags: forms

We have been having a sporadic issue with our CiviCRM forms. People will fill out a donation or event registration, hit submit, and the page will go white and not go to the confirmation page. It will happen randomly and sometimes several times in a row. Anyone else experience this and find a way to solve this issue?

Comment: A white screen can happen for a variety of reasons - you should check your website logs, your CiviCRM [ConfigAndLog logs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/15931/12), and the Drupal watchdog logs (if using Drupal) to find more information.  Then you can edit the question to include the additional information you find.  If you can't replicate the problem on demand, use the timestamps to find the last time it happened!  Also note that the problem may be in your CMS.

Comment: Thank you Jon. For now I just turned off the Confirmation Page component as it always errors out on that step, so I decided to see if having that off helps. It seems to confuse people to have that extra step anyways.