# CiviCRM will not load the database

Tags: wordpress, database

I am doing a fresh install of CiviCRM. Civi is using the WP database. When I use the Installer, I get the error "CiviCRM data from previous installation exists in 'db_WPyadayada'. Is there a way to delete all the Civi tables from 'db_WPyadayada' and connect Civi to another database?  I have another database 'db_wtf1' that has up to date contact info etc. from a previous installation.  If I try to connect to that database with the Installer I get the same error "CiviCRM data from previous installation exists in 'db_wtf1'.  Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Hi this seems like the same as your other question (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35342/when-reinstalling-civicrm-it-will-not-allow-connection-to-a-database-with-preex)? It's better to edit the original question which will push it to the top of the list, rather than have duplicates in stackexchange.

Comment: OK, thanks @Demerit.