# Are we able to see why a payment failed?

Tags: civicontribute, payment

Our contribution pages are working for some individuals and for others, payments are failing. Is there a way to see what the cause of this issue is for the payments that are unable to go through?

Comment: Which payment gateway are you using? Can you check in there for the failure reason?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few places you can check.

- Foremost, I would check your payment processor's logs.  Most likely the cards were sent there and declined.  Make sure you don't have any configuration mismatches - e.g. not allowing credit cards from outside your country, or requiring a CVV on the payment processor but not on CiviCRM (though I believe it's mandatory in CiviCRM on the front end these days).
- Check your CiviCRM logs.  Their location [varies by CMS](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/12).  If you're not sure how to interpret them, you may want to open a new question.

Comment: or add the Log Viewer extensions? https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer