# How do I add debug lines?

Tags: wordpress, debugging

Currently, I'm developing a civi extension in a Wordpress environment. I want to add some debug lines to make sure I'm receiving the intended result from variable/function.

I refer this [guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/) it says the log files are saved in ConfigAndLog directory.but that directory is not available.

I want to know how to include debug lines in the code and from where I can view the results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the link you referenced it says you can use `Civi::log()->debug();` [this section](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#viewing-log-files), so for example `Civi::log()->debug(var_export($my_variable, true));`

I'm not sure what you mean by the directory isn't available? This article says how to find it: [Where are the "ConfigAndLog" and "templates_c" directories?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)

Comment: Hi @demerit. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 3):

Re "where can I view the results" - if you want to view the log via the GUI try [the log viewer extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer).

Comment: cool. Thank you!