# Clean install on WordPress and blank dashboard

Tags: installation

After install on WordPress I am getting a blank dashboard and the "configure dashboard" button doesn't do anything. I tried deactivating all plugins except CiviCRM, that made no different. Any ideas what I should look at? All the settings seem to be correct.

Comment: I would first verify your Resource URLs: Administer --> System Settings --> Resource URLs.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced something similar (not sure if the same situation), but I solved it checking database credentials and domain  in civicrm_settings.php on wp-content/uploads/civicrm, may you could check if so.

Comment: I discovered an old out of date .htaccess file in the Plugins folder. Deleted that and the CiviCRM dashboard works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered an old out of date .htaccess file in the Plugins folder. Deleted that and the CiviCRM dashboard works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your web server user is different from the user who owns the files or ran the installer?  You can try deleting your [templates_c folder](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/12).  Also, check your Developer Tools tab (press F12) for errors, both on the Console and Network tabs.  If you find any, please edit your question to include them, they likely contain crucial info.

Comment: I discovered an old out of date .htaccess file in the Plugins folder. Deleted that and the CiviCRM dashboard works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found I was looking at the site on a different url than that defined in `civicrm.settings.php` - the CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL - and saw errors in the javascript console.

The dashboard is built dynamically by javascript, and it was trying to connect to the other domain, where I was not logged in.