# CiviCRM API issue

Tags: api, permissions

On our multi-site build we have been using the API functionality to send member info to a partner platform so that when a member logs in to our one of our websites and clicks a link their information is fired off to the partner allowing them to avoid loging in to the partner website.

For some reason new contacts can no longer directly access the third party website and instead are faced with the login page. Contacts that have previously accessed the third party are ok.

We receive the following error message;

```
Array
(
    [error_code] => unauthorized
    [entity] => Membership
    [action] => get
    [is_error] => 1
    [error_message] => API permission check failed for Membership/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM and access CiviMember
)
```

Members currently have the following permissions;

```
CiviCRM: add contacts
CiviCRM: view my contact
CiviCRM: access uploaded files
CiviCRM: profile listings and forms
CiviCRM: profile listings
CiviCRM: profile create
CiviCRM: profile edit
CiviCRM: profile view
CiviCRM: access all custom data
CiviEvent: register for events
CiviEvent: view event info
CiviEvent: view event participants
CiviPayment: access CiviPayment
CiviPayment: make online contributions
CiviMember: access CiviMember
CiviMail: access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages
```

Can anyone shed light on this.

Many thanks for your help.

Robbie

Comment: Do you see any permission difference between the old members and the new contacts?

Comment: Also you get more info if you check the [logs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) and paste the backtrace here.