# Beta 29-beta1 - Anyone see a problem where creating an event, after the first page settings it hangs on trying to get to any other tab?

Tags: civicrm-event

Subject says it all.  Has anyone ever seen this on the Beta (or any other version)?

Comment: can you check the civicrm logs to see if any error is logged when you hit the issue?

Comment: Sorry for a newb question...,  is this a url visible report or a file in the os?

Comment: It's a file - see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories

Comment: This is what I get..  [warning] hook_civicrm_volunteer_projectDefaultSettings should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke().

Comment: I saw this on 5.28.0 the other day - but I chalked it up to my installed the "entity settings" extension.  I didn't explore further.

Comment: I don't have that extension installed.  Yours still isn't working?