# Can't pay for Civi Event using Stripe

Tags: civievent, payment-processor, stripe

I am trying to configure CiviEvent, but have a problem and don't know where to look.

- I have two test sites, as far as I can see both configured the same.  CiviCRM 5.29.1, Stripe 6.5.1. Simple test Event set up.
- On One site I can configure Events that work OK if not paid for or paid for using credit card with Stripe (with a test card only so far).  On the other it works if not paid for, but Stripe fails.
- When failing it flashes up the 'Wait while Pre-authorising' message, but then returns to the registration page asking to have the card number put in again.
- When failing the Stripe log shows an Authorised but Uncaptured payment.
- There are no errors in the Drupal log.

Can anyone suggest anywhere to look that might help find this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is purely local to the questioner's site, and has no wider usefulness.

Comment: Since it's your own question, I believe you can just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a side-effect of a custom Module we have installed for something else (still related to Events).  Consider this question closed.

Answer (score 1):

I would look in your Stripe dashboard at "Events" (found under the "Developer" section of the navigation menu).  You're likely to find an event associated with the failure with an error message in its details.

Also, errors on your end are much more likely to be in the [CiviCRM log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/15931/12) than the Drupal log.

Comment: The Events contain just the following:

A new payment ... was created.
An uncaptured payment for £5.00 was created ...
The amount_capturable for payment [first reference] was updated

I mention Drupal log because I have configured all Civi log messages to be written to Drupal log as well.