# Upgrade from 5.33 to 5.34 failed

Tags: upgrade

Database upgrade from 5.33 to 5.34 on Drupal 7 fails while (I think) updating smtp password.  Reverting to the backup works fine, but I can't use the current version.

From the log :

```
Mar 01 08:39:03  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\"qfKey\";s:37:\"31de1ced9ac5fcb7d624eecee9479c4d_7696\";s:15:\"outBound_option\";s:1:\"3\";s:13:\"sendmail_path\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"sendmail_args\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"smtpServer\";s:20:\"ssl://smtp.gmail.com\";s:8:\"smtpPort\";s:3:\"465\";s:8:\"smtpAuth\";s:1:\"1\";s:12:\"smtpUsername\";s:17:\"info@wiser.org.za\";s:12:\"smtpPassword\";s$
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\"qfKey\";s:37:\"31de1ced9ac5fcb7d624eecee9479c4d_7696\";s:15:\"outBound_option\";s:1:\"3\";s:13:\"sendmail_path\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"sendmail_args\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"smtpServer\";s:20:\"ssl://smtp.gmail.com\";s:8:\"smtpPort\";s:3:\"465\";s:8:\"smtpAuth\";s:1:\"1\";s:12:\"smtpUsername\";s:17:\"info@wiser.org.za\";s:12:\"smtpPassword\";s:$
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\"qfKey\";s:37:\"31de1ced9ac5fcb7d624eecee9479c4d_7696\";s:15:\"outBound_option\";s:1:\"3\";s:13:\"sendmail_path\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"sendmail_args\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"smtpServer\";s:20:\"ssl://smtp.gmail.com\";s:8:$
)


Mar 01 08:39:03  [debug] $backTrace = #0 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(942): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...")
#3 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...")
#4 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1928): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...", "1366 ** Incorrect string value: '\x9B\x11\xCAD\x84M...' for column 'value' at...")
#7 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1234): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...")
#9 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...")
#10 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query("UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...")
#11 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(447): DB_DataObject->query("UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...")
#12 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1558): CRM_Core_DAO->query("UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\\"qfKey\\";s:37:\\"31de1ced9ac...", TRUE)
#13 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FiveThirtyFour.php(158): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = %2 WHERE id = %1", (Array:2))
#14 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php(74): CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FiveThirtyFour::migrateSmtpPasswords(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
#15 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(202): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
#16 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(36): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(TRUE)
#17 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(90): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#18 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(38): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#19 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#20 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#21 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#22 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(459): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#23 [path]/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("upgrade", "queue", "ajax", "runNext")
#24 [path]/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#25 {main}


Mar 01 08:39:04  [info] $CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX_runNext_error = PEAR_Exception: "DB Error: unknown error"
 * ERROR TYPE: DB_Error
 * ERROR CODE: -1
 * ERROR MESSAGE: DB Error: unknown error
 * ERROR MODE: 16
 * ERROR USERINFO: UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\"qfKey\";s:37:\"31de1ced9ac5fcb7d624eecee9479c4d_7696\";s:15:\"outBound_option\";s:1:\"3\";s:13:\"sendmail_path\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"sendmail_args\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"smtpServer\";s:20:\"ssl://smtp.gmail.com\";s:8:\"smtpPort\";s:3:\"465\";s:8:\"smtpAuth\";s:1:\"1\";s:12:\"smtpUsername\";s:17:\"info@wiser.org.za\";s:12:\"smtpPassword\";s:$
 * ERROR DEBUGINFO: UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = 'a:10:{s:5:\"qfKey\";s:37:\"31de1ced9ac5fcb7d624eecee9479c4d_7696\";s:15:\"outBound_option\";s:1:\"3\";s:13:\"sendmail_path\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"sendmail_args\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"smtpServer\";s:20:\"ssl://smtp.gmail.com\";s:8:\"smtpPort\";s:3:\"465\";s:8:\"smtpAuth\";s:1:\"1\";s:12:\"smtpUsername\";s:17:\"info@wiser.org.za\";s:12:\"smtpPassword\";s$
#0 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler()
#1 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct()
#2 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct()
#3 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR::_raiseError()
#4 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1928): PEAR->__call()
#5 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError()
#6 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#7 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1234): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery()
#8 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query()
#9 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query()
#10 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(447): DB_DataObject->query()
#11 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1558): CRM_Core_DAO->query()
#12 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FiveThirtyFour.php(158): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery()
#13 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php(74): CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FiveThirtyFour::migrateSmtpPasswords()
#14 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(202): CRM_Queue_Task->run()
#15 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(36): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext()
#16 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(90): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#17 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(38): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call()
#18 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#19 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#20 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#21 [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(459): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#22 [path]/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke()
#23 [path]/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#24 {main}


Mar 01 08:39:34  [info] $CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy_reportError = Array
(
    [is_error] => 1
    [is_continue] => 0
    [exception] => Error 1: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in [path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php, line 832
    [last_task_title] => Migrate SMTP password
)
```

Comment: If you edit your question to provide the [debug and backtrace from the log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) folks can better help you.  Please also mention your PHP version?

Comment: Can you try this patch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19711/files

Comment: That works.  Thanks.