# After update CiviCRM Birthday reports stopped working

Tags: civireport

Before reports came every day with a list of people who have a birthday today, we updated CiviCRM to version 5.35.1 and reports stopped coming, even in CiviCRM it does not give a list with birthdays, its just empty.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there anything in the log file showing an error? There isn't a core birthday report so is this provided by an extension?  If so, you could try creating an issue for that extension.

Comment: Martin's earlier question suggests it's a civireport that's mailed via cron. But agree checking the log is a good place to start: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/181

Comment: Thank you! At first i will try with update module!