# Civicrm - Expense extension [unable to edit expenses]

Tags: civicase, administer

Having trouble to figure out whats wrong with the edit expense function as it always return a blank page. What could be the issue?

I extracted the error code from the error log.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My setup environment:
Wordpress
Civicrm 5.35.1

[image: Blank page shown when trying to edit]

[image: After clicking edit button]

Comment: To be sure, you mean this extension https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/expenses ?

Comment: A network error usually hides another error. When you disable popup screens (Can be done at https://<server>/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1 and look for enable popup, and uncheck), the real error is shown.

Comment: Try opening the page/form on a new tab

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be a bug in the expenses extension. It's hitting [line 121](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/expenses/-/blob/e07563be5c1339e827931e686f22a48edf945df4/CRM/Expenses/Form/Expense.php#L121) in CRM/Expenses/Form/Expense.php but `$this->_expense` is a string instead of an array at that point.

It's not clear why it's a string - it gets set at [line 46](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/expenses/-/blob/e07563be5c1339e827931e686f22a48edf945df4/CRM/Expenses/Form/Expense.php#L46) - if you add something like `CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message(var_export($this->_expense, true));` either at line 48 or at line 120 and then check in the [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/181) file it will tell you what it looks like.

Comment: Below is the error log i got from ConfigAndLog:>


Mar 27 12:08:30  [info] Creating canary table


Mar 27 12:08:43  [warning] Deprecated function CRM_Core_BAO_Setting::setItem, use refer docs for correct methods https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/setting/.
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)

Mar 28 05:34:02  [info] 'Expense'

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the log in the post >Mar 28 05:46:43  [info] 'Expense'

Comment: Ok great so that's confirming it's the literal string 'Expense' instead of an array. That's weird.

Comment: What should i do?
 Is there any part of the code need to change?

Comment: Do you have anything in the civicrm_expense database table that looks weird?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the database on the post. 
I do not see anything weird.