# DB Error: unknown error fresh install godaddy

Tags: error

When trying to rebuild triggers (also rebuilds the phone number function) I get an Error DB Error: unknown error on a fresh install joomla / godaddy.

Comment: Can you check in [your civi log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories?rq=1) - the full error should be in there.

Comment: have you read  hosting requirements https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#mysql-permissions - does godaddy meet those specs?