# Test mail fails to send from outbound mail setup

Tags: smtp

First time installing Civicrm. Test mail fails to send from outbound mail setup. It shows everything is OK and mail sent, but it isn't. Tried mail() and SMTP with the same results. If I mis-configure SMTP, it throws an error as expected, so it is at least connecting to the mail server. This is a staging site on an A2 hosted server. Latest Wordpress, PHP V7.3 with required modules loaded. I contacted A2 and they gave me another mail server to try, but it has the same problem. I have tried both SSL and non-SSL with no change. Strangely if I check "Authentication" to no, it dosn't show an error, even though the mail server requires it. I set up the same email in Outlook and it works fine, so there is no problem with credentials. Any help is greatly appreciated, as I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Are there any errors listed in [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/15931/181)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I gave up on the staging site, as I ran into other errors. Created a test site on another domain and it works fine.