# I cannot merge contacts. I'm not a programmer so i can't seem to fix the issue

Tags: error

[image]

I cannot merge contacts at all. I have no idea what my next step should be.

Comment: Either check in ConfigAndLog (see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) to see the full error or at Administer - System Settings - Debugging turn on "Display Backtrace" and then repeat the dedupe and then it will show you the full error on screen.

Comment: I'm guessing, based on the error message, that you are using Joomla? Please edit the question to add the versions of Joomla (or other CMS if that's not correct) and CiviCRM.

Comment: To say what's been said slightly differently - if you follow Demerit's advice to turn on [debugging mode and backtrace](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#using-the-built-in-debugging-tools), you should edit your question to include the full error, and people can help you better.  Also, it's best to copy/paste the text instead of a screenshot - other people with the same problem will find this by searching, and it also makes it easier for folks who help troubleshoot because they don't have to retype the messages.