# Failure to Upgrade to 5.43.2

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I'm running it on wordpress.
I get to the point of "Point your web browser to the following URL

http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 "

I run the upgrade and it says nothing but [] on the scree and nothing else.

I'm not a developer, and we are just trying to get it all set up as I'm learning CiviCRM. Any help would be most useful.

Comment: Check the browser javascript console and also the log in the [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories?r=SearchResults&s=2|39.1828) folder.

Comment: Welcome @cassiday-moriarity  - could be helpful to know what version you were upgrading from. If you are unsure of how to see your browser console check here -> https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-your-browser-to-diagnose-javascript-errors/#step-3-diagnosis under step three. You want to look out for anything in red! Note these errors disappear when you reload the page. The other place that it's good to check for errors is the ConfigAndLog log file - you should find it under wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/ look at the most recent .log file there.