# "Current and Upcoming Events" is missing and trying to ICalendar.tpl.php file that does not exist

Tags: civievent, drupal, error, php, templates

Ive been thrust into trying to help a buddy fix his civicrm deployment and I cannot find a way to generate this template necessary to populate that page.

Looking at the errors it is looking for the following file but it isn't there. The directory is there and empty.

```
templates_c/en_US//%%45/45F/45F354E8%%ICalendar.tpl.php
```

I can figure out that there is a ICal.tpl file in the default templates folder, but I can't figure out how to regenerate the tpl.php file anywhere, nor did my poor attempts to hacking at php templates and copy it over work.

What generates the pre-pended ID? Is there a way to regenerate this file directly? I have no idea if its a custom template or not, but I dont think it is.

I have searched and have found nothing

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error message? With a stack trace if you have it (see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories). The templates_c folder is a cache folder that holds compiled templates and will regenerate as needed, assuming the web server has write access.

Comment: To add on to what @Demerit said - `templates_c` can be deleted at any time and it will be automatically regenerated.  If a file isn't there, it's generally a permissions issue; check the file permissions and the file owner.  The file owner should be the same user that PHP runs under - e.g. `www-data` on Debian w/ `mod_php`, or the user specified by your `pool.d` if running `php-fpm`.

Comment: Turns out, it was permissions. I have no idea how that got broken since no one should have been touching this. Thanks @JonG-MegaphoneTech