# Unable to export participants list from an event registration

Tags: civievent, registration, online-registration

I am trying to export the participant details for an event, however, I keep getting the error message below

PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in /home/ifm/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 922

- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown

I have never had this before and have been using CiVi for years

Any ideas what has gone wrong?

Comment: Look in [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) for the error, or temporarily turn on "display backtrace" under administer - system settings - debugging.

Comment: To add to the last comment - If you enable "debugging" and "backtrace", you'll get a much more detailed error.  You should then edit this question to include that info, which will allow folks to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful