# Payment failed When Using Payments With Webform CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm, authorize.net

I am trying process a payment with Authorize.net but I tried PayPal too. I using a Drupal (9.3.9) site with Webform (6.1.3) integrated with CiviCRM Webform (6.2.0). In both cases I get "Payment failed".

Is there documentation for configuring payment with CiviCRM Webform? That might be all I need.

I have a Participant Fee from my event that the person is registering for.

I am not sure what else to share that would be helpful in figuring out why this is not working.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is documentation here:

- [D9 Webform CiviCRM - Contribution](https://docs.civicrm.org/webform-civicrm/en/latest/configure-elements/elements-contribution/)
- [D9 Webform CiviCRM - Contribution Example](https://docs.civicrm.org/webform-civicrm/en/latest/examples/contributionwebform/)

If these don't get you up and running, a few other thoughts:

- What is your CiviCRM version?
- Have you tested payment separately from webform, using a standard CiviCRM event registration or contribution page? This would help pin down whether the issue lies with the payment processor setup or the webform integration.
- Does your configuration differ from what's shown in the docs?
- Are there any error messages in the logs? (See [Where are the "ConfigAndLog" and "templates_c" directories?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories))

Comment: Good points! Those docs are a bit outdated though. You no longer need to set up a Contribution page. MRs welcome!

Comment: I am sorry I did not update this a while ago. I am not sure what I changed but it started in most cases.