# "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." when trying to create mailing

Tags: civimail, mosaico, flexmailer

I'm receiving an error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." whenever I try to create a new mailing. If I disable Mosaico and FlexMailer the CiviMail system appears to load correctly, but as soon as I reenable FlexMailer the error returns.

I updated to CiviCRM 5.52.3 earlier today, and also updated the Drupal Views and EU Cookie Consent modules, but otherwise haven't changed anything since this morning when it was working.

I've tried clearing Drupal caches, the Cleanup Caches option in CiviCRM, and deleting all files in sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/. So far nothing has made a difference.

I can't see anything in ConfigAndLog with a timestamp matching when I'm trying to create a mailing.

Comment: might it relate to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39134/civicrm-core-now-includes-flexmailer-how-to-remove-old-flexmailer-extension ?

Comment: That does seem to have fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(because StackExchange likes Answers more than Comments)

Probably relates to conflict of having the old flexmailer extension now that flexmailer is included in civicrm core.

[CiviCRM core now includes Flexmailer: how to remove old flexmailer extension?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39134/civicrm-core-now-includes-flexmailer-how-to-remove-old-flexmailer-extension)