# Is there a log or record of CiviCRM updates I've done?

Tags: logs, install

Our scheduled jobs stopped working on December 8. Is there a way to see if we updated our installation at, or around, that date?

We have updated once after that. I can see some PHP files that have that date so it seems reasonable that we did an update then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table civicrm_log has a record of updates - if you filter/query the civicrm_log.data column for "update" you might see what you want.

You can also access via API Explorer with something like

[image]

EDIT You may need to set the "limit" set higher than default 25, and "order by id desc" to help see the latest entries. (from comment by thoni56)

Comment: I needed to have "limit" set radically higher than default 25, and "order by id desc" also helped to see the latest updates. Thanks.

Comment: Tx - i added that in to answer as some folk may not read beyond the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a log of when files in the filesystem were changed? That isn't recorded in civi. If you mean a log of when CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/XXX scripts were run then it depends how you ran it. If you ran using the UI then it will be in ConfigAndLog. If you ran using cv then it depends if you logged the output anywhere.

Comment: Please explain how to find the date of CiviCRM updates in the log files in ConfigAndLog.

Comment: e.g. grep for "update" in [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)