# Cannot Complete Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, database

Earlier I wrote in with a question about a database upgrade failing because of date constraints ([Upgrade to 5.57.1 Fails With Error executing task "Fix dangerous delete cascade"](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43326/upgrade-to-5-57-1-fails-with-error-executing-task-fix-dangerous-delete-cascade)).  I did not think that this failure left the database partially upgraded.  In retrospect this make sense but it did not occur to me at the time.

I think I tried with both cv and the CiviCRM Upgrade page (/civicrm/upgrade).

Now after fixing the dates I am unable to upgrade the database because the database is in a partially upgraded state. I get the following error with CV.

> Found CiviCRM database version 5.57.alpha1.upgrade.

> Found CiviCRM code version 5.57.3.

> In UpgradeDbCommand.php line 80:

> Cannot resume upgrade: The log file
> (/root/.cv/upgrade/dcda99f3a7060a8eeb8c255df45c3907.dat) is missing.
> Consider a regular upgrade (without --retry or --skip).

I have tried both --skip and --retry and I get the same message.

I have not removed any files from the /root/.cv/upgrade/ directory and this is the only CiviCRM install I have on this server.  There is another dat file in the directory but I do not think it is the right one as it appears to shown a successful upgrade.

Reverting back to a database before attempting the upgrade is not a viable option.

Is there anything I can do? I appreciate any help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `UPDATE civicrm_domain SET version='5.56.0';` in mysql and then run the upgrade normally. Sometimes this causes different problems because some steps are not rerunnable, but I don't think that will happen between 5.56 and 5.57.

Comment: Thank you, thank you!! This worked well.