# Error 500 when saving anything

Tags: wordpress

I have installed CiviCRM using wordpress:latest and running it inside a docker container.

After installing CiviCRM, any change I do in the system by saving, I get a 500 error

[image]

Can someone give me clues on how to fix this?

The log from ConfigAndLog file is below -

> wordpress/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog$ tail -f
> CiviCRM.1_03e8e875ec930fd208c5c90d.log  Jan 23 15:36:30  [debug]
> $backTrace = #0
> /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441):
> CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
> #1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39):
> CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
> #2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
> #3 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
> #4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
> #5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
> #6 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
> #7 {main}

Comment: You might find more info about the error in [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) but based on the error it's possible that you have CIVICRM_BASEURL set incorrectly in civicrm.settings.php. Check if it is http vs https too, because if part of the page is using http and part is using https it might not think it's the same session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I dont have civicrm.settings.php.  Could not find anywhere except in the uploads folder.  My site is http.  The configAndLog output is attached to the issue.

Comment: The civicrm.settings.php in your uploads folder is most very likely exactly the one you need!