# Allow anonymous users (not logged in) to edit their fields?

Tags: contacts, profile, user, checksum, urls

The question is simple:

I have created a profile, but I would like to share a URL to the anonymous user so they can fill out the profile **WITHOUT LOGGING IN** and these responses will go to their contact.

Do you know if there is a way to do it by sharing the ID by URL, as if it were a GET method?

The url to the profile could be something like this:

https://my.page/civicrm/profile/edit/?gid=22&reset=1&id=123

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs for checksums: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#checksum

Comment: I understand that this solves the main point of my problem, but these links can only be sent by email and they also expire. That could make things difficult because some contacts were registered with wrong emails.

Comment: You can also manually generate a checksum for a contact using Support - Api4 explorer with entity Contact and action getChecksum. Then put that in the url in place of the token from the docs.

Comment: I don't really understand the email comment though - how would you be sending these links to them?

Comment: The URL I need is the following: http://example.org/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=IDNUMBER&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}, however I understand that the { } are tokens for the CiviMail component. I don't understand when the previous URL works so that an anonymous user can edit the profile information with the corresponding ID in the URL

Comment: At api4 explorer, run the contact.getchecksum api call putting in the desired contact id. That will give you a checksum. Put that and the contact id into your url in place of the {} tokens.

Comment: If you don't use checksums, your proposed solution allows _any_ unauthenticated user to change these fields for _any_ contact just by changing the id in the URL.  That's bad!

Comment: @Aidan I know it's bad but it's exactly what I need :(

Comment: @Demerit I have tried but when I receive the verified link and click on it, the page is displayed with this legend "No results of the type have been found."

Comment: Might have something to do with the fields configured on the profile? Or maybe there is more information about the error in [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)?