# civicrm_post hook not firing upon contact creation

Tags: wordpress, hooks

I am writing a custom plugin for wordpress that stores contact data when a new individual is created in CiviCRM. I wrote a test function to see if the 'civicrm_post' hook fires when a new individual is created, but the body inside the function doesn't execute (ie. nothing is logged to console)

This is the code:

```
function appeal_generator_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {
        echo "<script> console.log('contact has been adjusted') </script>";
}

add_action( "civicrm_post", "appeal_generator_civicrm_post", 10, 4 );
```

I have also tried the postCommit hook as well as copy-pasted the demo code for the civicrm_post hook that is on the civicrm website, but nothing executes when a new individual is created.

I have checked that the plugin is correctly setup within the /wp-content/plugins directory and that it is activated on wordpress, and there are no errors in the server logs.

Is there a different hook I should be using or is there a setup issue with the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hooks run in php not javascript, so it won't log anything to the js console.

If you want to log, use `\Civi::log()->debug('hello');` and then look in the [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) directory in the logs there.

Or use `error_log('Hello');` and then check whereever that goes (usually the web server log).

Or even more low-level:

```
$fp = fopen('/path/to/my-own-log-file', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'Hello');
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I added the \Civi::log() line and now can see the output in the civicrm ConfigAndLog file. Thanks for the tip.