# Unable to save changes to report

Tags: civireport

I copied a report and updated the filters for what I am looking for in addition to changing the title. When I select "Save" or "Save a Copy" from the dropdown menu, neither works. Not sure what has changed because I used to be able to do this in the past. Any help would be much much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Mary - welcome!  Do you know what version of CiviCRM you're on? It should be at the bottom of every CiviCRM page.

Comment: Hi Jon! CiviCRM 5.57.4.

Answer (score 1):

Without more info this is difficult to pin down, but I can offer several suggestions of where to look.

- Ensure you have the necessary permissions - either "Administer CiviCRM" or the relevant CiviReport permissions.  They're at **Administer menu » Users and Permissions » Permissions (Access Control)**, then click "Drupal Access Control" (or WordPress/Joomla/Backdrop Access Control, whichever is appropriate).  "Save Report Criteria" is the big one.
- If permissions are good, check the log for errors.  I don't know if you're at all technical and/or if you have permission to install CiviCRM extensions.  If you're more technical, you can [view the logs on the server](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/12).  If not, go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions**, click the **Add New** tab, and install [CiviCRM Log Viewer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer).  After that, logs will be in **Administer menu » Administration Console » Log Viewer**.

I recommend viewing the log, noting the most recent entry's number.  Then immediately replicate the issue, reload the logs, and see if you have new entries.  If so, I recommend editing your question to paste in everything from the new log entries.  That should give folks most or all of the info needed to give a solution.