# DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown During Member Report Export

Tags: wordpress, error, core, pear

CiviCRM v5.65.1 WordPress v6.3.1 Self Hosted with cPanel

The error I get when I go to Find Membership-Select X Members-Export (total number 16): Civi\Core\Exception\DBQueryException: DB Error: unknown error in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 945

- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown

Error Info: Code -1 Message DB Error: unknown error

Mode    16

**UserInfo**

CREATE TABLE `civicrm_tmp_d_export_2ee0d31f6054ecb9b46a1e8157fa15b4` ( id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `civicrm_primary_id` varchar(64), `contact_type` varchar(64), `external_identifier` varchar(64), `display_name` varchar(128), `organization_name` varchar(128), `contact_sub_type` varchar(255), `first_name` varchar(64), `middle_name` varchar(64), `last_name` varchar(64), `do_not_email` varchar(64), `do_not_phone` varchar(64), `do_not_mail` varchar(64), `do_not_sms` varchar(64), `do_not_trade` varchar(64), `is_opt_out` varchar(64), `legal_identifier` varchar(32), `sort_name` varchar(128), `nick_name` varchar(128), `legal_name` varchar(128), `image_url` longtext, `preferred_communication_method` varchar(255), `preferred_language` varchar(5), `hash` varchar(32), `contact_source` varchar(255), `prefix_id` varchar(255), `suffix_id` varchar(255), `formal_title` varchar(64), `communication_style_id` varchar(255), `email_greeting_id` varchar(64), `postal_greeting_id` varchar(64), `addressee_id` varchar(64), `job_title` varchar(255), `gender_id` varchar(255), `birth_date` varchar(32), `is_deceased` varchar(64), `deceased_date` varchar(32), `household_name` varchar(128), `sic_code` varchar(8), `user_unique_id` varchar(255), `current_employer_id` varchar(64), `contact_is_deleted` varchar(64), `created_date` varchar(32), `modified_date` varchar(32), `addressee` varchar(255), `email_greeting` varchar(255), `postal_greeting` varchar(255), `current_employer` varchar(255), `location_type` varchar(255), `address_id` varchar(64), `street_address` varchar(96), `street_number` varchar(64), `street_number_suffix` varchar(8), `street_name` varchar(64), `street_unit` varchar(16), `supplemental_address_1` varchar(96), `supplemental_address_2` varchar(96), `supplemental_address_3` varchar(96), `city` varchar(64), `postal_code_suffix` varchar(12), `postal_code` varchar(64), `geo_code_1` varchar(32), `geo_code_2` varchar(32), `manual_geo_code` varchar(64), `address_name` varchar(255), `master_id` varchar(128), `county` varchar(64), `state_province` varchar(64), `country` varchar(64), `phone` varchar(32), `phone_ext` varchar(16), `phone_type_id` varchar(64), `phone_type` varchar(255), `email` varchar(254), `on_hold` varchar(64), `is_bulkmail` varchar(64), `signature_text` longtext, `signature_html` longtext, `im_provider` varchar(255), `im` varchar(64), `openid` varchar(255), `world_region` varchar(128), `url` varchar(255), `membership_type` varchar(128), `member_is_test` varchar(64), `member_is_pay_later` varchar(64), `membership_join_date` varchar(32), `membership_start_date` varchar(32), `membership_end_date` varchar(32), `membership_source` varchar(128), `membership_status` varchar(255), `membership_id` varchar(64), `owner_membership_id` varchar(64), `max_related` varchar(64), `membership_recur_id` varchar(64), `member_campaign_id` varchar(64), `member_is_override` varchar(64), `componentpaymentfield_total_amount` varchar(32), `componentpaymentfield_contribution_status` varchar(255), `componentpaymentfield_received_date` varchar(32), `componentpaymentfield_payment_instrument` varchar(255), `componentpaymentfield_transaction_id` varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY ( id ), INDEX index_street_address( street_address ) , INDEX index_household_name( household_name ) , INDEX index_civicrm_primary_id( civicrm_primary_id ) ) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci [nativecode=1118 ** Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.]

**DebugInfo**

CREATE TABLE `civicrm_tmp_d_export_2ee0d31f6054ecb9b46a1e8157fa15b4` ( id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `civicrm_primary_id` varchar(64), `contact_type` varchar(64), `external_identifier` varchar(64), `display_name` varchar(128), `organization_name` varchar(128), `contact_sub_type` varchar(255), `first_name` varchar(64), `middle_name` varchar(64), `last_name` varchar(64), `do_not_email` varchar(64), `do_not_phone` varchar(64), `do_not_mail` varchar(64), `do_not_sms` varchar(64), `do_not_trade` varchar(64), `is_opt_out` varchar(64), `legal_identifier` varchar(32), `sort_name` varchar(128), `nick_name` varchar(128), `legal_name` varchar(128), `image_url` longtext, `preferred_communication_method` varchar(255), `preferred_language` varchar(5), `hash` varchar(32), `contact_source` varchar(255), `prefix_id` varchar(255), `suffix_id` varchar(255), `formal_title` varchar(64), `communication_style_id` varchar(255), `email_greeting_id` varchar(64), `postal_greeting_id` varchar(64), `addressee_id` varchar(64), `job_title` varchar(255), `gender_id` varchar(255), `birth_date` varchar(32), `is_deceased` varchar(64), `deceased_date` varchar(32), `household_name` varchar(128), `sic_code` varchar(8), `user_unique_id` varchar(255), `current_employer_id` varchar(64), `contact_is_deleted` varchar(64), `created_date` varchar(32), `modified_date` varchar(32), `addressee` varchar(255), `email_greeting` varchar(255), `postal_greeting` varchar(255), `current_employer` varchar(255), `location_type` varchar(255), `address_id` varchar(64), `street_address` varchar(96), `street_number` varchar(64), `street_number_suffix` varchar(8), `street_name` varchar(64), `street_unit` varchar(16), `supplemental_address_1` varchar(96), `supplemental_address_2` varchar(96), `supplemental_address_3` varchar(96), `city` varchar(64), `postal_code_suffix` varchar(12), `postal_code` varchar(64), `geo_code_1` varchar(32), `geo_code_2` varchar(32), `manual_geo_code` varchar(64), `address_name` varchar(255), `master_id` varchar(128), `county` varchar(64), `state_province` varchar(64), `country` varchar(64), `phone` varchar(32), `phone_ext` varchar(16), `phone_type_id` varchar(64), `phone_type` varchar(255), `email` varchar(254), `on_hold` varchar(64), `is_bulkmail` varchar(64), `signature_text` longtext, `signature_html` longtext, `im_provider` varchar(255), `im` varchar(64), `openid` varchar(255), `world_region` varchar(128), `url` varchar(255), `membership_type` varchar(128), `member_is_test` varchar(64), `member_is_pay_later` varchar(64), `membership_join_date` varchar(32), `membership_start_date` varchar(32), `membership_end_date` varchar(32), `membership_source` varchar(128), `membership_status` varchar(255), `membership_id` varchar(64), `owner_membership_id` varchar(64), `max_related` varchar(64), `membership_recur_id` varchar(64), `member_campaign_id` varchar(64), `member_is_override` varchar(64), `componentpaymentfield_total_amount` varchar(32), `componentpaymentfield_contribution_status` varchar(255), `componentpaymentfield_received_date` varchar(32), `componentpaymentfield_payment_instrument` varchar(255), `componentpaymentfield_transaction_id` varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY ( id ), INDEX index_street_address( street_address ) , INDEX index_household_name( household_name ) , INDEX index_civicrm_primary_id( civicrm_primary_id ) ) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci [nativecode=1118 ** Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.]

Exception Trace:

0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:945
1   PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: unknow…', -1, 16, Array, 'CREATE TABLE `ci…')    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php:997 2   DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, Array, 'CREATE TABLE` ci…')   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:575
3   PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -1, 16, Array, 'CREATE TABLE `ci…', 'DB_Error', true)    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:223 4   PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1928 5   DB_common->raiseError(-1, null, null, 'CREATE TABLE` ci…', '1118 ** Row size…') /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:943
6   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:413
7   DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('CREATE TABLE `ci…') /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1234 8   DB_common->query('CREATE TABLE` ci…')   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2696
9   DB_DataObject->_query('CREATE TABLE `ci…')  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1829 10  DB_DataObject->query('CREATE TABLE` ci…')   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:487
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query('CREATE TABLE `ci…', false) /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1650 12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('CREATE TABLE` ci…', Array, true, null, true, false) /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/SQL/TempTable.php:171
13  CRM_Utils_SQL_TempTable->createWithColumns(' id int unsigned…') /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Export/BAO/ExportProcessor.php:2114
14  CRM_Export_BAO_ExportProcessor->createTempTable()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Export/BAO/Export.php:173
15  CRM_Export_BAO_Export::exportComponents(true, Array, Array, '`membership_join…', null, null, 3, ' civicrm_members…', null, 0, 0, Array, null)   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Export/Form/Select.php:297
16  CRM_Export_Form_Select->postProcess()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:624
17  CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144
18  CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Member_Export_Form_Select), 'next', 'Next')   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43
19  CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Member_Export_Form_Select), 'next')  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
20  HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Member_Export_Form_Select), 'next')    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
21  HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('next') /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355
22  CRM_Core_Controller->run(Array, null)   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319
23  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
24  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
25  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199
26  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
27  WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:334
28  WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:517
29  do_action('toplevel_page_Ci…')  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:259
30  {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually seen a `utf8mb3` charset in the wild (it's the same as `utf8` but it never calls itself utf8mb3). I would probably:

- do a database backup
- Run the api System.utf8conversion to convert to `utf8mb4`. If the database is large, run it via command line e.g. `cv api3 System.utf8conversion`, otherwise you can also run it in the UI via api3 explorer with Entity=System Action=utf8conversion

utf8mb4 is the default on new installs now and definitely recommended over utf8. And it usually fixes this "row too large" error but even if it doesn't you want to be using utf8mb4.

Comment: QUICK! Thanks! Weird stuff now. Just upgraded BTW, but have an old snapshot. So, going to extensions triggers "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions." I can get into other things, but other oddity is that when I click System Status (is in white) takes me to a page with a wheel permanently spinning. Cleared cache and paths and small DB. And not sure how to get to the api3 explorer. Thanks!

Comment: I would check your [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) for errors. The api explorer in the UI is in the Support menu.

Comment: I will stay focused on the conversion right now. Neither APIv3 or APIv4 show utf8conversion and couldn't find it in any column no matter what I did - image link below. I have asked my provider to execute the command line command as not too familiar with how to do it and will report back. - https://imgur.com/a/IJ4zKZA

Comment: Argh sorry I made a typo - entity is "System" not Job. But also you are looking at api4 not api3. It's only available in api3. Direct url is `civicrm/api3`.

Comment: So, I ran your instructions through the UI and the attached screenshot shows a wheel spinning for the past hour. We only have a small handful of total Members and other than the payments function we don't do a whole lot with it. Any ideas how long it should go? Same issue as the System Status. Set error reporting as well for emails but nothing yet (thx for the other tips on Config&Log). https://imgur.com/a/zRlT4FZ

Comment: So, I rolled back to 5.64.3, my last snapshot and issues cleared up. I am now applying the DB upgrade through the UI. The little wheel is spinning like the above image. Any length of time that might be where I throw in the towel and ask my provider to roll back again and then ask them to do the charset conversion? Been running about half an hour now with only a handful of Members, but have had CiviCRM for years. Thanx

Comment: I run a couple of WordPress sites this one is "2" This is a screenshot of my databases and info: https://imgur.com/a/Xzgk5RI

Comment: I don't think the utf8 is the problem for the upgrade. The original question was about the export. For the upgrade problems, check the [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) for errors.

Comment: I will go through them. What cured the PEAR error, though, was the conversion to utf8mb4 while in the rollback of 5.64.3 snapshot I had. I then upgraded to 5.65.2 and have not experienced any issues. I will close this out and open with a new question when I come across new errors for brevity sake and thank you!

Comment: I notice also you're on mariadb 10.6. There was an issue with upgrade snapshots in some cases for that version. It's fixed in 5.66, but for 5.65 you might try putting `define('CIVICRM_UPGRADE_SNAPSHOT', FALSE);` in civicrm.settings.php temporarily. Reference: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27404

Comment: To make sure I understand, add only that portion to the civicrm.settings.php and not the green section in the github to Snapshot.php? And then what at the bottom of the file and then delete when I get to 5.66? Thanks!