# Uncaught PHP Exception - DB Error: no such field

Tags: php

Dears,

Any idea on how to find the origin of this issue ? Site says 'unexpected error, please try again later' ...

[Fri Dec 01 00:00:01.474392 2023] [error] [pid 319782] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(887): [client 66.249.66.23:0] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception Civi\Core\Exception\DBQueryException: "DB Error: no such field" at /data/sites/web/instituutvlaamsevolkskunstbe/cms-install/4466-instituut-voor-vlaamse-volkskunst/production/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Error.php line 971'

Comment: It's likely part of some civi upgrade didn't work so a table is missing a field. To see which field you'll need to look in the [civi log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) for the full error.

Comment: Ever since Drupal and CiviCRM started using Composer I'm running into one problem after the other :(