# Scheduled Reminder error: Expected one Case but found 25

Tags: error, scheduled-reminders

I'm using Civi 5.70.0 on WordPress. I'm trying to utilize the Scheduled Reminders, but when testing it, no email is being sent, and I'm getting this the message "Expected one Case but found 25". I saw all kind of similar messages, where instead of Case there were Contribution, PaymentProcessor, Contact etc. but none of Case. Furthermore, although I looked at some of the other questions and answers, I still don't understand what does the message mean nor how to cope with.

Comment: Is there more information in [ConfigAndLog](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories)?

Comment: Actually, no @Demerit. The same time stamp where the Scheduled Jobs Listing noting an error, the ConfigAndLog shows no error, just:

"2024-02-18 08:00:02+0000  [info] Sending Scheduled Reminder 1 to 1 recipients"

Comment: The Expected One Case but got 25 is where the CiviCRM API does not have a parameter - eg a case id to select the case and then pass that on. It just finds the first 25.  Any more details on how you are setting the Scheduled reminders up might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @TonyHorrocks. I've set a Reminder based on Activity. I selected one Activity Type, one Status, and added a relative date before the Activity Date to trigger it. I skipped the Effective From, and set Activity Assignee as Recipients