# CiviCalendar: Show DB Error

Tags: calendar

I have install CiviCalendar. However, the calendar can not shown in the CiviCRM dashboard. Moreover, when I click Contacts-> Contact calendar sharing, System show the below error:
"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Could not find valid value for cid
Return to home page"

[image: DB Error]

My WordPress Version is 6.4.3; CiviCRM Version is 5.70.2; Calendar Extention Version is 3.5.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM log to get more details about the DB Error. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want (but may help others). There is a solution underway for a calendar display based on Search Kit but see Aidan's comment below.

https://lab.civicrm.org/ayduns/calendarskdisplay

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my extension @petednz but it's at an early stage and not usable yet.  But any contributions welcome!

Comment: ah right. have tweaked the answer