Missing Relationship Cache Data fails to rebuild cache with DB error
I'm getting a "Missing Relationship Cache Data" warning on the CiviCRM status page after updating from 5.67.3 to 5.72.2. Clicking the button to rebuild cache shows a spinner and fails to rebuild the cache. I tried running the command
cv api4 RelationshipCache.rebuild

and also
cv ev 'CRM_Contact_BAO_RelationshipCache::rebuild();'

but it just outputs "In Error.php line 971: DB Error: unknown error"
How do I figure out where the error is, and get the cache rebuild to work? The status warning says Expected 52684 records, and that it found 0 in cache. In addition, now the relationship tab in contacts doesn't show any relationships when previously there used to be.
Civi is running on Drupal 7.100 with php 8.1.28. cv version is 0.3.48.
I checked logs in the ConfigAndLog folder, Drupal logs, syslog, php-fpm, nginx logs and get no information regarding the error.

check civicrm log for more details about the db error https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories

Civi log is not adding any new messages when I run the cv commands.

The issue was that a row in the end_date column of the civicrm_relationship table had an incorrect date value of '0000-00-00' when it should have been NULL.
I tracked this by watching the mysql log output where I found the sql query for rebuilding the relationship cache table. Running the query in phpmyadmin notified me of the error.
